# I want to group a PHP array using key values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to group a PHP array with a data structure like this:

```php
"data": [
        {
            "seq": "1",
            "created_month": "Aug"
        },
        {
            "seq": "1",
            "created_month": "Jul"
        },
        {
            "seq": "2",
            "created_month": "Aug"
        },
        {
            "seq": "2",
            "created_month": "Jul"
        }
    ]
```

I tried this:

```
$data   = array_column($data,'seq','created_month');
```

and I expected it to display as:

```
"data": [ {"seq": [{"Aug":1},{"Jul":1},{"Aug":2},{"Jul":2}]}]
```

Comment: Are you able to achieve it by foreach loop, if yes please share that code ? and it is not array only it is array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by the other user, `array_column` will not work here.

The [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) describe what the method does, and that's not what you want:

> array_column() returns the values from a single column of the input,
>   identified by the column_key

This should work though ([ideone](https://ideone.com/6EC7al)):

```
$data = '[
    {
        "seq": "1",
        "created_month": "Aug"
    },
    {
        "seq": "1",
        "created_month": "Jul"
    },
    {
        "seq": "2",
        "created_month": "Aug"
    },
    {
        "seq": "2",
        "created_month": "Jul"
    }
]';

$data = json_decode($data, true);
$transformedData = array();
$transformedData["data"] = array();
array_push($transformedData["data"], array("seq" => array_map('convertItem', $data)));

print_r(json_encode($transformedData));

function convertItem($item) {
  return array($item['created_month'] => intval($item['seq']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use array_column here because you have non-unique values. You need to loop through array. Please see below code

```
$data = json_decode( $data, true);

$formatArray = array();
foreach( $data as $d ) {
    $formatArray[] = array( $d['created_month'] => $d['seq'] );
}

$j = array();
$j['seq'] = $formatArray;
echo json_encode( $j );
```